# Android java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I got an error as of title. I know there are many answers but it didn't works.

What I did already,
First.
add code on build.gradle(Module:app)
"multiDexEnabled true" at defaultConfig  &
"compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'" at dependencies 
add code on AndroidMenifest
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" at application

Second.
add code on build.gradle(Project:~~)(I also tried on build.gradle(Module:app)
"dexOptions{
             javaMaxHeapSize "2g" (I also tried for "4g"
}"

First one was not works which means show same error.(Out of memory)
Second one was show another error(could not find method~~) which means I use higher targetSDKVersion to use it.(My app is 23 for targetSDKVersion.)

So there were no answer until I tried google it....
How could I solve it....?
is there anybody who can help me?
I'm waiting for you such a kind person.... Thank you in advance.....

Comment: Check your code on memory leaks

Comment: You probably thrashed your heap. Search for this term